# Django template filter date not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters

I'm on django 1.4.

I pass the `MY_VAR` variable to the home.html template.
The code showed is simplified. Here's the `urls.py`

```
import home
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # homepage
    url(r'^/?$', home.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
)
```

And the view `home.py`

```
from django.conf import settings     

class Home(TemplateView):
    """ this view serves the home template """
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

        data = {
            'MY_VAR': setting.MY_VAR # where MY_VAR defined in settings.py is a string '2014-12-31'
        }

        retun data
```

I have a template variable that I then embed in js:

```
<!-- source code of home.html --> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   var myVar = '{{ MY_VAR }}'
</script>
```

`MY_VAR` is in the form `'2014-12-31'`. 
If I don't use any filter then things work, meaning that the above piece of code will produce this:

```
<!-- computed home.html --> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   var myVar = "2014-12-31";
</script>
```

but I would like a different date formatting, so if I use a `date` filter as this

```
var myVar = '{{ MY_VAR|date }}'
// or
var myVar = "{{ MY_VAR|date:'d-m-Y' }}"
```

I always get an empty string `var myVar = ''` no matter what I pass to the date filter. Also the default `{{ MY_VAR|date }}` without any formatting param returns an empty string.

Comment: Could you post how you are passing the variable from views.py ? Is the original variable a string ou datetime object?

Comment: I edited the question (twice, I did forget a piece of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem in views.py using datetime module and passing a datetime object, like:

```
from datetime import datetime
...
data = {
        'MY_VAR': datetime.strptime(settings.MY_VAR, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
         ....
        }
return data
```

Comment: Thanks! So I suppose the data passed to the template should be a date type in the first place. I tough that passing a string would be handled as well by the `date` filter, but it seems it's not true.